# Using Gulp and .pipe() when parameters aren't yet ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm using some Gulp plugins to help automate the building of a Cordova app. Below they are the functions that start with `gulp_cordova_`. The way I understand Gulp (or node.js streams) to work is that each .pipe() is called pretty much immediately with whatever function/parameters are given. The function they each return is queued up for later execution. My problem is that I want to pass in options to `gulp_cordova_plugin()` that I don't have values for until after `Config.getConfig()` has hit an endpoint.

Is this possible with Gulp?

Note: `options` below is some environment information that each `gulp_cordova` plugin needs. I piggyback onto of it with the `config` key.

```
gulp.src(dist)
.pipe(gulp_cordova_create(options))
.pipe(Config.getConfig(options))
.pipe(gulp_cordova_plugin({
    'phonegap-facebook-plugin': {
        version: '0.12.0', 
        variables: { 
            'APP_ID': options.config.app_id, 
            'APP_NAME': options.config.app_name
        }
    }
}, options));
.pipe(gulp_cordova_build_android(options))
.pipe(gulp_cordova_build_ios(options));
```

I have considered writing a wrapping function that know how to use the correct values and just invokes `gulp_cordova_plugin` itself, but the problem I'm having seems like something that would have been accounted for.

Comment: Could you run `Config.getConfig(options)` before you run `gulp.src`, or is there a reason why it has to be in the pipe?

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen I think the piping was kind of blinding me to other options, I think that would work for me, thanks!

Comment: Did it work? If so I'll create an Answer :-)

Comment: Sure, I could accept it as a solution to my problem. It does seem like shortcoming of gulp that everything would need to be available by them time you create a chain though. Thanks!

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen should have directed that to you.